# Zend Framework 2 - Service method require as parameter InputFilter

Tags: oop, zend-framework2

I have a bit OOD question.

I have service:

```php
namespace Front\Service\Course;

use Front\ORM\EntityManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Front\InputFilter\Course\CreateFilter;

class Create implements EntityManagerAwareInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager = null;

public function create(CreateFilter $createFilter)
{
    if (!$createFilter->isValid()) return false;

    /* @var $courseRepository \Front\Repositories\CourseRepository */
    $courseRepository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Front\Entities\Course');
    $course = $courseRepository->findByName($createFilter->getCourse());
}

/* (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see \Front\ORM\EntityManagerAwareInterface::getEntityManager()
 */
public function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->entityManager;
}

/* (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see \Front\ORM\EntityManagerAwareInterface::setEntityManager()
 */
public function setEntityManager(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    return $this;
}
}
```

And controller :

```php
class CreateController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController
{

    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $jsonModel = new JsonModel();

        /* @var $courseCreateService \Front\Service\Course\Create */
        $courseCreateService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Front\Service\Course\Create');

        $courseCreateFilter = new CreateFilter();

        $courseCreateFilter->setData($this->params()->fromPost());

        if (!$courseCreateFilter->isValid()) {
            $jsonModel->setVariable('status', 0);
            $jsonModel->setVariable('message', $courseCreateFilter->getMessages());

            return;
        }

        $courseCreateService->create($courseCreateFilter);

        }
 }
```

By service method declaration :

```php
    public function create(CreateFilter $createFilter)
```

i force user of the Service to use CreateFilter container which derived from Zend/InputFilter every time when he want to create new Course.

My question is: Might it be better when i will send to the service layer not the Typed object but simple value? 
On example in my case it is might looks like:

```php
public function create($courseName)
```

My CreateFilter looks like:

```php
class CreateFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $input = new Input('name');

    $validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();

    $validatorChain->addValidator(new StringLength(array('max'=>60)))
                   ->addValidator(new NotEmpty());

    $input->setRequired(true)->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

    $this->add($input);
}

/**
 * @return string | null
 */
public function getCourse()
{
    return $this->getValue('name');
}
}
```

Comment: If you expect it to be an input filter, your class should reflect that, but rather than forcing the concrete class implementation, why not just require the class provided implements `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface`?

Comment: First, it is not my dependency it is user input from Service point of view. And it is must have concrete method getCourse defined inside CreateFilter.

Comment: If the service expects it to have a getCourse method, then your filter class should implement an interface that defines that. My point stands, your service should expect an object implementing that interface instead of a concrete class name, rather than being typeless.

Comment: Okay, i understand your point. But CreateFilter has concreate implementation of input filtering why should i provide an Interface for it ? If i will expect an interface, than i will have to check is the given object is instance of CreateFilter, because only Create filter has required business logic. Please correct me if i miss something.

Comment: I append CreateFilter code to the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a concrete class name as you're doing now, you're forever tied to a concrete implementation of the class or one derived from it. If you decide later that you want to use a different class entirely, you have to refactor your service class code, whereas with an interface, you only need to implement it in your new class and your service will continue to work without any changes.

Without any interface at all, your service class would have to do extra checks to first see if it's an object and then if it implements the method you're expecting before it can even begin doing its job. By requiring an interface you remove the uncertainty, and negate the need for checks.

By providing an interface you create a contract between your methods and the classes they're expecting as arguments without restricting which classes may enter into the contract. All in all, contract by interface is preferable to contract by class name, but both are preferable to no contract at all.

Comment: If i will define interface, how can i be sure that given object implement business behavior of CreateFilter ?

Comment: A class can implement as many interfaces as you need, if other methods of your service have other requirements, declare whatever interface is appropriate in the method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I usually bind my entities to my form, so they are populated with the data from the form. This way, you inject the entity to your service and imho that's much cleaner. The service should not be aware of how you got your data.

My "admin" controller for an entity Bar usually is injected with three objects: the repository (to query objects), the service (to persist/update/delete objects) and the form (to modify objects for the user). A standard controller is then very CRUD based and only pushes entities to the service layer:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Controller;

use Foo\Repository\Bar as Repository;
use Foo\Form\Bar       as Form;
use Foo\Service\Bar    as Service;
use Foo\Entity\Bar     as Entity;
use Foo\Options\ModuleOptions;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class BarController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var Repository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * @var Service
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * @var Form
     */
    protected $form;

    /**
     * @var ModuleOptions
     */
    protected $options;

    public function __construct(Repository $repository, Service $service, Form $form, ModuleOptions $options = null)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->service    = $service;
        $this->form       = $form;

        if (null !== $options) {
            $this->options = $options;
        }
    }

    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    public function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->repository;
    }

    public function getForm()
    {
        return $this->form;
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->options) {
            $this->options = new ModuleOptions;
        }

        return $this->options;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $bars = $this->getRepository()->findAll();

        return array(
            'bars'     => $bars,
        );
    }

    public function viewAction()
    {
        $bar = $this->getBar();

        return array(
            'bar' => $bar,
        );
    }

    public function createAction()
    {
        $bar  = $this->getBar(true);
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $form->bind($bar);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // Bar is populated with form data
                $this->getService()->create($bar);

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bar/view', array(
                    'bar' => $bar->getId(),
                ));
            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }

    public function updateAction()
    {
        $bar  = $this->getBar();
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $form->bind($bar);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->getService()->update($bar);

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bar/view', array(
                    'bar' => $bar->getId(),
                ));
            }
        }

        return array(
            'bar'  => $bar,
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->getRequest()->setStatusCode(404);
            return;
        }

        $bar = $this->getBar();
        $this->getService()->delete($bar);

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('bar');
    }

    protected function getBar($create = false)
    {
        if (true === $create) {
            $bar = new Entity;
            return $bar;
        }

        $id  = $this->params('bar');
        $bar = $this->getRepository()->find($id);

        if (null === $bar) {
            throw new Exception\BarNotFoundException(sprintf(
                'Bar with id "%s" not found', $id
            ));
        }

        return $bar;
    }
}
```

I made a gist file on Github with this full code (it's better readable) and the service. The service relies on the interface, so you can even swap out the entity object by another one having the same interface.

Check the full thing out here: https://gist.github.com/juriansluiman/5472787

Comment: Example above and by link, in controller and service breaks the SRP (Single responsibility principle). In controller constructor breaks the DIP (Dependency inversion principle) class depends from concrete class (Form object) but should depend from Abstraction by DIP. But anyway thanks, you gave me one more puzzle part =)

Comment: For the question you are asking (should I inject a InputFilter in my service layer) my example is -I think- the easiest to comprehend. Usually I rely on interfaces, but defining interfaces in a SO answer creates just a massive clutter. Can you explain why this controller does not handle SRP? And the same for the service? As far as I see it, there is no violation there ;)

Comment: To clarify more: your question is, should I `create` a typed object or simply a value. My answer is: **never** inject the input filter, but your entity (and there, an interface is better than a concrete instance). Also **never** make your service `EntityManagerAwareInterface` as it is really the *complete wrong* way of DIC with initializers for hard dependencies. Also **never** create controllers on an *action* base but on an *entity* base: don't use the `CreateController` but the `CourseController`. I think those are the more fundamental parts of coding I wanted to answer / help

Comment: 1. Your controller does not handle SRP because it is provide CRUD, CRUD it is 4 responsibilities.

Comment: 2. Actions in your controller does not defined by any interface, your controller just a container for procedures. (Where is the contract ?) If i will be client of your controller how should i know which public actions you have ?

Comment: 3. (don't use the CreateController but the CourseController) not good. What if i have 100 actions and all of them need different dependencies, and different contracts ? In your controller you have viewAction, but when your controller will be created it is will receive all dependencies which useless while you displaying viewAction, it is useless overhead.

Comment: 4. (Also never make your service EntityManagerAwareInterface as it is really the complete wrong way of DIC with initializers for hard dependencies) I agree, in constructor object initialization will be more clear for manual instantiation, but using setters for injecting dependencies it is not a crime, and not breaks DIP. I like Fowler [article](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorVersusSetterInjection) about this approaches (i mean Constructor injections vs Setter Injection).

Comment: 5. Service violation for SRP is the same with controller, too many actions in one Service. It is statefull procedure container.

Comment: SpalaX, not to insult you, but you just confirm my earlier comment you need to read some more about OOP programming and the OOP paradigms and principles. I will just address a few ones.

Comment: 1. CRUD is **not** four responsibilities. A responsibility is to handle the I/O around (a) certain domain layer object(s). Please check the definition of a controller, you see often it as a "police agent" to manage traffic. And there are multiple cars and streets for this agent, not just one.

Comment: 2. Controllers do have an interface, they are dispatchable. Requiring an interface for an action in a controller is just nonsense. Please read some more about even driven programming and look at the `MvcEvent` and `DispatchListener` specifically in zf2. A controller can dispatch a request, how the controller do this, is up to the controller. Interfaces for actions are just not proving whatsoever for additional programming by contract.

Comment: 3. A sign for a controller which has too many responsibilities. Split them, because a Course has **never** 100 things you can do with it. Then you just have poorly designed your domain layer. Always start with the domain layer (DDD gets increased attention), so if your controller can get 100 actions, just get back to your domain layer and redesign it.

Comment: 4. You probably haven't read the page completely? "Constructors with parameters give you a clear statement of what it means to create a valid object in an obvious place." "Another advantage with constructor initialization is that it allows you to clearly hide any fields that are immutable by simply not providing a setter." and "my preference is to start with constructor injection" (and the problems he refers to, are not you case for your service)

Comment: 5. Please read more about stateful if you use the term. About the domain layer, this service does **not hold state**. Only the entities itself hold state, but that is part of the definition of an entity. And here again: **methods do not count as SRP violation**. You seriously think 4 methods is too much?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answering, owing to answers and analyzing, i have reached conclusion which most applicable for my situation. I agree that Service in my case should not wait concrete object, it is should wait an abstraction with getCourse method.
And i completely agree with "Crisp" answer:

> All in all, contract by interface is preferable to contract by class name, but both are preferable to no contract at all.

So i need to extract Interface with one method 
    getCourse 
or 
    getName
, and remove

```php
if (!$createFilter->isValid()) return false;
```

so Interface:

```php
interface CourseInterface
{
  /**
   * @return String
   **/
  public function getName();
}
```

and Service:

```php
class Create implements EntityManagerAwareInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager = null;

/**
 * @param CourseInterface $course
 * @param UserInterface $creator
 */
public function create(CourseInterface $course)
{
    $courseEntity = new Course();

    $courseEntity->setName($course->getName());

    $this->entityManager->persist($courseEntity);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
.....
```

Thanks all.

Comment: No, you're now injecting a `CourseInterface` and creating a `CourseEntity`. You treat the implementation of the interface a value object where you rather should make your entity implement the interface. Yes, relying on an interface is preferred above relying on a concrete instance, but you are now mixing all things together. Don't treat an entity as a value object. They hold state, don't use the value objects to modify your state of entities, unless you are working towards an object model without setters (http://whitewashing.de/2012/08/22/building_an_object_model__no_setters_allowed.html)

Comment: CourseInterface it is a part of Data namespace, $course it is a data/value object it is not an entity. But thanks for your concern.